# Calling IntelliJ plugin from Gradle plugin

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

**Problem**:
I have developed a custom gradle plugin. I would like to have a blocking UI associated with it so as to take contextual input from the user during the build. Hence I created swing based UI for it. The problem with this approach is that, while running gradle build on IntelliJ, if this UI ever goes behind the IntelliJ window, I couldn't figure out a way of programatically bringing it on top of IntelliJ window.

Hence I am thinking of popping up an IntelliJ based UI **iff** the gradle build of the project is running on IntelliJ.

**Question**:
Is there a way to call a custom IntelliJ plugin's UI from a Gradle task?

Answer (score 2):

You can call a IntelliJ plugin from anywhere, if you open a Socket.

Grep Console plugin does that: https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole/tree/master/src/krasa/grepconsole/tail/remotecall

Comment: Thanks Meo, it's a good hint to start with. Any port/port-range that I should lean towards?

Comment: Some very high number probably, I would try googling it. I do not remember where I came up with my default number...

Comment: Thanks Meo for pointing me towards GrepConsole. I was able to do what I wanted, just by using ConsoleFilterProvider.